# Setting a dynamic drop down value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on this issue for days and feel like I'm at a dead end so hoping someone can help out.

I have a form that's used to log calls.  The form has two drop downs **Reason** and **Resolution** which are created using an array.

When a call is dropped for whatever reason I want the user to click a button called **Lost Call** and have it fill out the form with specific information.

It works for every field but the **Resolution** field. I can't get that one to populate.

The lost call button calls a function using onClick.

```
<Input type="button" value="Lost Call" onClick="LostCall()" />
```

All my code is HTML5 and JavaScript.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select id="Reason"><option value=" "></option></select>
<select id="Resolution"><option value=" "></option></select>
```

The script I use to create the drop downs I got from here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/

Other then changing the Variable names to suit my form and less options the code is the same.

The Question is how can I make it to where someone clicks lost call the form is filled out including the Reason and Resolution with specific values when the Resolution values are dynamically generated?

Here is the script for the Lost Call Button:

```
function LostCall() {
      var Reason = document.getElementById("Reason");
      Reason.Value = 'Misc/Other';
      var Resolution = document.getElementById("Resolution");
      Resolution.Value = 'Lost Call';
```

Using the above Reason is populated but not Resolution. Also note both **Misc/Other** and **Lost Call** are options available in the array I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRv2W/1119/).

---

Hmm, your code is working, as I've tried it in this quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRv2W/1117/)

Are you simply missing a closing `}` or was that just a simple mistake when typing this question?

Comment: No it's not the missing }. The issue is my select attribute are place holders. The actual options for the drop downs are dynamically generated using the script from link in my question. It's not a standard select with options.

Comment: Omg that works awesome.  One question how do I get it to clear the value it added if the user goes in and clicks on reason and choose something else?

Comment: Also as an addition to if someone hits reset in the form to clear the added option too.

Comment: Awesome. Works great

Answer (score 0):

if the value you are assigning in the list of options, try this approach:

```
function LostCall() {
    document.getElementById("Resolution").selectedIndex = "2";
}
```

check out the following resource (press the "try it yourself" button) : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Comment: How do I get it to choose the specific index when it's dynamically generated using an array? I am using the JavaScript array that I linked in the JS fiddle.